# Advice on CMS, ExpressionEngine vs. Drupal or?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, expressionengine

I'm currently stuck between a rock and a hard place. I need to
identify a new CMS for my company but I am struggling (we're a digital
agency and produce tens of websites a year of varying sizes for
retained clients.)

We currently use MySource Matrix (which is a blackbox, no technical
documentation) as our CMS and the Zend Framework for our applications.

My requirements are that templates are available via FTP only so they
can be stored in an external VCS and edited in an IDE. Templates
should have a templating language like smarty so pure PHP cannot be
misused in them.
It would be good if we could continue to develop in a 90% ZF way. If
the CMS comes with a reasonable framework then we would embrace it to
drive synergies between CMS projects and other bespoke applications
projects.

I'm not satisfied that either Drupal or EE solve my first point.
Drupal enforces FTP templates but allows PHP to be entered in
templates. I don't know how compatable the smarty engine module is (it
hasn't been updated since 2007). EE has a reasonable template syntax
but doesn't enforce maintenance via FTP (you can easily edit the
template via the browser and break external version control.)
My second point is not ideal either. Drupal and ZF 2 are at polar
opposites of the programming spectrum. EE has CodeIgniter but on
initial inspection it's very light and we'd largely still use ZF to
the extent that we may as well not use CI.

Other issues are that of functionality. Drupal looks superior on this
front. It's core has most features that we require. To use EE we'd
have to install a few paid for add-ons before we start (templating,
wysiwyg and taxonomy.)

Noting my two requirements (coming from a ZF background and wanting
synergies and forcing FTP for templates that don't allow PHP) can
anyone help me make a decision between the two and or suggest another
CMS that might be better suited.

In terms of suggesting another CMS, it must have a strong community,
documentation, be pretty much be open-source and have a number of high-profile websites built upon it.

Comment: Smarty allows PHP, too. `{php} echo "PHP'ed"; {/php}`.

Comment: True but you can disable that in the config, likewise with EE's engine.

Comment: Smarty was updated Jun 3 las time, version 3.0.8, Anyway it sounds like you should be looking at Django, is not PHP but it has what you are asking for.

Comment: @ramono I was talking about the Drupal Theme Engine that implements Smarty, not the core project... See http://drupal.org/project/smarty

Comment: As far as FTP templates go in EE, I say this: You could create member groups that don't allow access to the control panel's Template Manager, thereby forcing all users (besides your superadmin account) to edit via FTP.

Comment: Also, regarding EE's commercial add-on market: while it may seem too expensive to purchase add-ons for what may seem like core features, these add-ons help keep EE's core lightweight. They can also help increase the quality of EE's add-ons, since those sales drive additional development and product support.

Comment: @Bitmanic thanks for both comments. EE certainly has the edge for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up going for EE. Thanks @Bitmanic for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

how about tomatoCMS: http://www.tomatocms.com ? it is coded in ZF and uses 960gs. it is very complete and very simple at the same time, lots of features and easily to extend, it gave us excellent results here :)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had stumbled across this one before but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have a large enough community and user base. Technically it looks very promising though.

Comment: That's right. This was an issue for us as well. We decided to take the risk anyway, because no other CMS fit our requirements (just like in your case, our needs were very similar). So far, so good, though. We haven't had any issues at all, and since we use ZF here for some stuff, it was trivial to extend it with new widgets (note that i'm not talking about patches, but just extending its widgets and adding some very specific new modules, otherwise, its shipped with a lot of common features you'd expect in a top quality cms). just my 2 cents :)